# SecurityFilterChain bean loaded in initilization but ignored on HTTP Requests

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I implemented a custom Filter for my Spring-boot application, but still couldn't get the request to go through the SecurityFilterChain bean.

Here is the code inside my bean. Its being loaded when I start the application but being ignored when I do a request, any idea what could be the problem?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ProjectSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and().cors().configurationSource(new CorsConfigurationSource() {
                    @Override
                    public CorsConfiguration getCorsConfiguration(HttpServletRequest request) {
                        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
                            config.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("http://localhost:4200"));
                        config.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));
                        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
                        config.setExposedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("Authorization"));
                        config.setMaxAge(86400L);
                        return config;
                    }
                }).and()
                .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
                .and()
                .addFilterAfter(new JWTTokenGeneratorFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .addFilterBefore(new JWTTokenValidatorFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("api/login", "api/registration/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "api/questions/**", "api/exams").hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "api/users/").hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .antMatchers("api/questions/**", "api/exams", "api/complete-exam").hasRole("USER")
                .and().formLogin()
                .and().httpBasic();

        return http.build();
    }

}
```

I tried some configuration, dissabling the deafultFilters in the spring app with: @SpringBootApplication(exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })

But still request are not passing through this FilterChain.

Comment: The filter will only be be added to the chain when it matches a url. 
Just put a break point in FilterChain where the filters gets added to the list and see why your custom filter is not added.

Answer (score 0):

Just rename your bean from `defaultSecurityFilterChain` to a different name because that one is already the default one created by Spring and yours will be overriden.

Comment: I modified the name, but still the configuration is not being taken to the request.
A clear example is that I'm setting the CORS configuration to allow the request from my Angular App, but still getting the CORS error on Chrome Client. Even that its configured as stated above. What Spring Scurity configuration may I be missing?

Comment: https://github.com/ali-bouali/spring-boot-3-jwt-security
In this repo there is an implementation of SPring security (the correct way)
Also you can check my youtube channel for the detailed video.
https://youtube.com/@boualiali
this SecurityConfig class contains exactly what you need to configure the CORS
https://github.com/ali-bouali/gestion-de-stock-api/blob/master/src/main/java/com/bouali/gestiondestock/config/SecurityConfiguration.java